# C : Recursive Function to Iterative

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I would need to convert this function to iterative, but all I can think of is recursion, and when I think about iterative, in my mind it would turn out a mess (aka many nested for)...

```
      void FrattaleRicorsivo(char scacchiera[][32], int n, int m, bool black)
    {
      int mediano;
      //Soluzione del caso di base.
      if (m == 0)
      {
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          m--;
          mediano = (n - 1)/2;
          if (black)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              {
                  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                  {
                      scacchiera[i][j] = 'D';
                  }
              }
          FrattaleRicorsivo(&scacchiera[0][0], mediano + 1, m, true);
          FrattaleRicorsivo(&scacchiera[0][mediano + 1], n - mediano - 1, m, false);
          FrattaleRicorsivo(&scacchiera[mediano + 1][0], mediano + 1, m, true);
          FrattaleRicorsivo(&scacchiera[mediano + 1][mediano + 1], n - mediano - 1, m, true);
          }
          else
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              {
                  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                  {
                      scacchiera[i][j] = ' ';
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
void main()
{
    int n = 32;
    char scacchiera[n][n];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        scacchiera[i][j] = 'X';
    }
}
FrattaleRicorsivo(scacchiera, n, 6, true);
```

}

The bidimensional array starts black, aka filled with 'X'.
Basically what this function does, is divide the bidimensional array into 4 squares, and the top right square becomes "white" while the rest have D and marked black. Then it divide each of those squares into 4 more squares, with the same rule, except the fact that if the square is a white one, it remains white.
How would I make it iterative without writing a mess?

Comment: You could have a pair of nested loops to traverse the grid, stepping at first by half the grid size. Each block within that iteration is then divided into 4 sections if it is black. Next time around, halve the step of the outer loops, finishing when the step was `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happened to recognize the pattern, so I have no analytical method to show how to transform the original code to this solution. I just knew it:

```
static void Fill(size_t n, char (*A)[n])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        A[i][j] = j == 0 || i != 0 && A[i-1][j-1] != A[i-1][j] ? 'D' : ' ';
}
```

The pattern is seen in [Pascal’s triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), using D for each odd entry and space for each even entry. In Pascal’s triangle, each entry after the first row is the sum of the two entries just to the left and right above it. So it is even if and only if the two entries above have the same parity. We merely need to account for the start (`i` is zero) and the left edge (`j` is zero).

Comment: Both yours and Weather Vave replies were helpful, Weather Vave gave a nice idea to actually change the code from recursive to iterative without writing a mess (just 2 for and a function that analize the block ^^), while you gave a way better and faster method to simply do the task. Thank you both!